# Can’t shrink volume because it shows that volume may be corrupted

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, windows-11, chkdsk

I am running Windows 11 the SSD with an issue is a Kingston SNVS5500G.

I already have tried running `chkdsk /f` and `chkdsk /r`, `Sfc /scannow`, `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and nothing got fixed.

I know that my SSH is not corrupted as everything works just fine. So what is happening?

This is the error I see:

[image: error]

Comment: Run `chkdsk` on the disk to see if it finds errors. Do not use yet the `/f` parameter (fix) as this can be destructive. Check also the SMART attributes of the disk (post them if you wish verification).

Answer (score 0):

Some software,such as [Macrium Reflect](https://forum.macrium.com/3908/Can-Macrium-Reflect-resize-partitions-when-restoring-to-a-smaller-drive) and [Acronis](https://kb.acronis.com/content/2770), enable you to resize the partition during reinstallation.

1. Make a complete, *verified* disk image of the SSD on external media.
2. Using disk management tools such as Windows *DiskMgmt.msc* or [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), **carefully note** the size, order and type of all partitions. A screenshot might help, but **written** notes can be viewed before the OS is installed.
3. *If* the drive hosts the OS, boot from USB or DVD using a third-party ISO, e.g., [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/hirens-boot-cd-allinone-boot-cd/) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/hiren39s-bootcd/) that has disk partitioning tools, such as [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) or [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html).
4. Using one of those disk tools, remove *all* partitions, recreate partitions of the desired sizes, and format them appropriately.
5. Finally, restore the image *to fit the resized paritions*, using the tool from step 1.

**Caveat:** SSD's have limited lifetime, determined primarily by the number of *writes* to each cell. If it's failing, you may to restore the image to a replacement device. Note that at one time, [Windows OS had issues](https://www.tomsguide.com/news/windows-10-update-could-kill-your-ssd-what-you-need-to-know) which could cause early SSD failure.

Comment: The advice is good, but checking the disk should be the first step.

Comment: @harrymc, "I already have tried running chkdsk /f and chkdsk /r", from OP. Do you have a suggestion for other ways to check the SSD? SMART?